# Unclear TLS Rec Layer-1 Encrypted Alert

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl, iis-6

I am trying to access a remote webservice from an asp.net application in an iis 6 server to a remote webserver. 
As I wasn't able to connect, I used MS Network Monitor to look over what was happening.

This is the TLS progress

```
2   15:26:31 14.03.2013 0.0000000       yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.    {TLS:4, SSLVersionSelector:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
3   15:26:31 14.03.2013 0.0312500       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Server Hello.; TLS Rec Layer-2 HandShake: Certificate.   {TLS:4, SSLVersionSelector:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
4   15:26:31 14.03.2013 0.0312500       yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Certificate. Client Key Exchange. Certificate Verify.; TLS Rec Layer-2 Cipher Change Spec; TLS Rec Layer-3 HandShake: Encrypted Handshake Message.   {TLS:4, SSLVersionSelector:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
5   15:26:31 14.03.2013 0.0468750       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 Cipher Change Spec; TLS Rec Layer-2 HandShake: Encrypted Handshake Message. {TLS:4, SSLVersionSelector:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
6   15:26:31 14.03.2013 0.0781250       XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 Encrypted Alert {TLS:4, SSLVersionSelector:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
```

And this is final TLS transaction with the alert

```
  - TlsRecordLayer: TLS Rec Layer-1 Encrypted Alert
     ContentType: Encrypted Alert
   - Version: TLS 1.0
      Major: 3 (0x3)
      Minor: 1 (0x1)
     Length: 18 (0x12)
     EncryptedData: Binary Large Object (18 Bytes)
```

And finaly this is the hex dump for the alert part.

```
15 03 01 00 12 CE CA A3 1C C9 44 5C AC A2 3C BB 3C F3 F9 8A A6 4F 22
```

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Alert_protocol I tried to decode the meaning

```
15 = 21 dec <- always 21
03 01 = major and minor Version
00 12  = lentgh
```

And now it gets weird. Normaly the next two bytes should be the level and description of the alert. But they make no sense. Beside that, they differ every trace I run. While the front part stays constantly the same.

Any ideas how i can decrypt the alert?

My first thought was that the other side may not allow TLS 1, while IIS 6 only supports TLS 1 (atleast that is what i thougt).

Thanks alot in advanced

Answer (score 1):

The alert itself is encrypted, because the handshake was successful. So before you know what it says, you have to decrypt it - you could use ssldump, in case you have the server's private key.

Found this here: http://www.wireshark.org/lists/ethereal-users/200110/msg00055.html - after I puzzled about the same problem for a while.

This is about ssldump: http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/

Using Wireshark, you can decrypt everything, in case you have the private key that was used for encryption: http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx116557